# Can't save empty string in model in Yii

Tags: php, yii

My code is very simple:

```
if ($code) {
    $code->code = $_POST['code'];
    $code->save();
}
```

When `$_POST['code']` have a value like `"12345"` or `abcde` it will be saved without problems. But when `$_POST['code']` is `""`, the there is no saving. So, I can't set empty string for this field to replace the previous value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is default value for that column `NULL` ?

Comment: @S.I., It initialized as `VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL` but has no default value.

Answer (score 0):

check your validation rule. you may define some validation rule please check it.

or print your model validation error

```
 $code->code = $_POST['code'];
 $code->save();
 print_r($code->getErrors());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **try-catch** when saving **data** in database. Doing that will show you the error/issue

```
if ($code) {
    $code->code = $_POST['code'];

    try {
        $code->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the the code property of the module is not required in the validation rules.
Example:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('code', 'safe'),//or some other validation as below
        //array('code', 'length', 'max'=>255),

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like this,

```
if ($code) {
if($_POST['code'] != ""){
$code->code = $_POST['code'];
}else{
$code->code = "";
}
$code->save();
}
```